# I/O Java required int

Tags: java, io, try-catch

I am trying to use I/O to give a report on the stock that I need (if the stock is below 8).

It tells me it requires an `int` for `myShop.listLowStockToFile());`; when I add a number it tells me that '`void` is not allowed here'. How can I fix this?

```
  public void listLowStockToFile(int threshhold)
   {
   System.out.println("****The Stock that is getting low is: " + " Minimum " +threshhold + " Report for Bob Shaw****\n");
   for (Item nextItem : items)
   {
   if(nextItem.getNuminStock() < threshhold)
   {
       System.out.println(nextItem);
   }
}
}

public class Report {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shop myShop = new Shop();

        CD cd1 = new CD("Abba Gold", "Abba", 15);
        myShop.addItem(cd1);

        Game game1 = new Game("Chess", 2, 39.95);
        myShop.addItem(game1);

        ElectronicGame eg1 = new ElectronicGame("Shrek", "PS2", 1, 79.50);
        myShop.addItem(eg1);
        ElectronicGame eg2 = new ElectronicGame("Doom", "PC", 2, 30.20);
        myShop.addItem(eg2);
        ElectronicGame eg3 = new ElectronicGame("AFL", "PS2", 2, 49.95);
        myShop.addItem(eg3);


        cd1.receiveStock(3);
        game1.receiveStock(5);
        eg1.receiveStock(10);
        eg2.receiveStock(1);
        cd1.receiveStock(7);


        cd1.sellCopy(true);
        cd1.sellCopy(true);
        eg2.sellCopy(true);

        myShop.listItems();
        myShop.listLowStockToFile(8);
        myShop.listGamesByPlatform("PS2");
        myShop.calcTotalSales();

        Game game2 = new Game("Chess", 2, 39.95);
        myShop.addItem(game2);

        eg2.sellCopy(false);

        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("LowStock.txt"));
            writer.write("Report dated" + new Date() + "\n");
            writer.write(myShop.listLowStockToFile()); // This line.
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Report finished");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("File I/O error" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've not shown the relevant code; but I'm going to guess that `listLowStockToFile` has return type `void`, not a value type.

Comment: `listLowStockToFile` takes an `int` and returns nothing (`void`) so you can't use it like `writer.write(myShop.listLowStockToFile());` or `writer.write(myShop.listLowStockToFile(8));`

Comment: so any ideas on what i can do?

Comment: @Bob It would help if you showed the `listLowStockToFile()` method and explained what you want it to do.

Comment: sorry new to this, is that enough to go on?

Answer (score 0):

You need `listLowStockToFile` to return a String:

```
public String listLowStockToFile(int threshhold) {
   String rtn = "****The Stock that is getting low is: " + " Minimum " +threshhold + " Report for Bob Shaw****\n";
   for (Item nextItem : items) {
      if(nextItem.getNuminStock() < threshhold) {
         rtn += nextItem.toString() + "\n";
      }
   }

   System.out.print(rtn);

   return rtn;
}
```

The reason is that `BufferedWritter.write` takes a `String` as an argument.

Comment: lets me compile, but gets rid of the threshold from my output I'm afraid

Comment: By "output" I assume you mean stdout (console). You can simply add in `System.print(rtn)` to `listLosStockToFile`

Comment: when you say add a System.print(rtn) would that be instead of the return rtn at the end of the code you wrote?

Comment: Just put `System.out.print(rtn)` before `return rtn`. I updated my answer to reflect this change.